# Git unable to discard local changes

Tags: git, github

I am unable to discard local changes. Furthermore, another strange thing is happening where git does not include the two files in the screenshot when I check the code in. It's always these two files.

I tried to doing the "git reset --hard command" several times as well as undoing the changes through the UI but nothing works.

git status shows the two files as being modified
git reset --hard say the HEAD has been changed to the commit on the server but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Are you working with an IDE or other similar tool which may be automatically making changes to these two files?

Comment: git reset -- hard

Comment: Yes and nothing. The changes are still there

Comment: Yes, I'm working in Visual Studio. This only started happening lately. I make a change to these two files, check them in. I can see the changes have been pushed to the remote server but these two files still appear in my local changes.

Comment: _Close_ Visual Studio completely, then do `git reset --hard` from the Git bash.  Tell us what happens.

Comment: I closed Visual Studio and did the command git reset --hard then git status and these changes are still there just like the screenshot.

Comment: I also tried "git stash" and then "git stash drop" and "git add ." then "git reset --hard" but they are still there.

Comment: One more piece of info, I can switch branches without git complaining that I cannot do that because I have uncommitted changes like it usually does.

Comment: Are these changes tracked already?

Comment: Does `git diff` print any changes?

Comment: Use `git clean -f -d`

Comment: This is almost certainly end-of-line meddling. (Sometimes this is a "files of same name but different case" problem, but I suspect end-of-line issues.)

Comment: Could this be a problem with a case-insensitive file system? Do you have other files with the same names but different case?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to use the wrong Git command to achieve what you want. Git reset command is used to place your HEAD at a specified state and **do not** discard your changes in your working directory.

To perform this, try using the git checkout command with the name(s) of the file(s) you want to discard, see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

In this case, it will be :

```
git checkout -- Model/DataModel.edmx -- Model/DataModel.edmx.diagram
```

**EDIT** *(From comment below)* **:** Otherwise, if theses files are added to the git repository and they don't belong to it, just move or remove them with classics `mv` or `rm` commands.
Also, [git rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) is maybe what you need there.

Comment: just `git checkout .` would do the trick here I guess. However, it is risky since it will revert all changes in the current directory (and nested directories).

Comment: I'm not sure about nested for this but it definitively accomplish what we want here in a shorter way.

Comment: JeuneAppreti - it's not working. The files are still there. the only thing I'm able to do is to move the files between staged and unstaged status.

Comment: @JeuneApprenti - Well, I am very sure about that. You can try it if you don't believe me :)

Comment: Apparently there might be some problems with line endings in so I executed command "git config core.filemode false" as suggested by some but it has made no change.

Answer (score 0):

These changes were on a development branch. The only way I was able to "discard" these changes was by committing them to the server. I then merged from our master branch into the development branch to everything is nice and equal.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced this situation when the same file has been committed on Windows with different casings in the file path or name. You'll know if this is affecting you by cloning the repo somewhere else, you'll see something like this:

```
the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'FilePath/File.txt'
  'filepath/File.txt'
```

You can see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646733/266104) for some potential options for fixing it.